How to define an aggregate analytics view in surrealdb for time-series data
I'm trying to have a table that aggregates 1min candles into 5min candles, my 1min candles look like this:
[
    {
        close: 1.10278dec,
        high: 1.10278dec,
        id: Candle:[
            d'2024-08-18T21:04:00Z'
        ],
        low: 1.10278dec,
        open: 1.10278dec,
        volume: 1dec
    },
    {
        close: 1.10278dec,
        high: 1.1028dec,
        id: Candle:[
            d'2024-08-18T21:05:00Z'
        ],
        low: 1.10278dec,
        open: 1.10278dec,
        volume: 19dec
    },
    {
        close: 1.10278dec,
        high: 1.10278dec,
        id: Candle:[
            d'2024-08-18T21:06:00Z'
        ],
        low: 1.10278dec,
        open: 1.10278dec,
        volume: 4dec
    },
]

I can aggregate them using this select statement:
SELECT
    Candle_5min:[time::floor(array::first(id[*]), 5m)] AS id,
    array::first(open) AS open,
    math::max(high) AS high,
    math::min(low) AS low,
    array::last(close) AS close,
    math::sum(volume) AS volume
FROM Candle
GROUP BY id;

and it gives me candles like this
[
    {
        close: 1.10278dec,
        high: 1.10278dec,
        id: Candle_5min:[
            d'2024-08-18T21:00:00Z'
        ],
        low: 1.10278dec,
        open: 1.10278dec,
        volume: 1dec
    },
    {
        close: 1.1026dec,
        high: 1.1028dec,
        id: Candle_5min:[
            d'2024-08-18T21:05:00Z'
        ],
        low: 1.1025dec,
        open: 1.10278dec,
        volume: 46dec
    },
    {
        close: 1.1026dec,
        high: 1.10262dec,
        id: Candle_5min:[
            d'2024-08-18T21:10:00Z'
        ],
        low: 1.1026dec,
        open: 1.10262dec,
        volume: 22dec
    },
]

which is exactly what I want.
but when I try to define a table to have an aggregate analytics view using this query:
DEFINE TABLE Candle_5min AS
    SELECT
        Candle_5min:[time::floor(array::first(id[*]), 5m)] AS id,
        array::first(open) AS open,
        math::max(high) AS high,
        math::min(low) AS low,
        array::last(close) AS close,
        math::sum(volume) AS volume
    FROM Candle
    GROUP BY id;

I get this error:
'Incorrect arguments for function array::first(). Argument 1 was the wrong type. Expected a array but found 1.10278dec'
what am I doing wrong and what is the correct way of achieving this?
thanks
